# How Can I extend a qtquick control?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

Here in [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html) a custom control named `PieChart` has been created by extending `<QtQuick/QQuickItem>` But I need to extend `QQuickTextEdit` I tried to find it but it seems `QQuickTextEdit` class is not available in in Qt framework. So I'm not able to extend it. Where could I find it?

How Can I extend a particular qt quick control (such as `TextArea` or `TextBlock`) in c++?

Comment: QQuickTextEdit is defined in `./qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquicktextedit_p_p.h`, 
`./qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquicktextedit.cpp`, 
`./qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquicktextedit_p.h`. As the suffix `_p` indicates, its header is private, so it is not intended to be used from C++. You can extend it in QML. What is your goal?

Comment: @SimonWarta thanks for your comment. I need to extend it as a terminal console. I want to develop it in c++ because all functions and key input handlers are already developed for `QPlainTextEdit`. I do not want to rewrite all of them in `qml`.

Comment: So the way to go is probably to use [Keys.pressed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#pressed-signal) to capture a key event and call a C++ function from there. This function can handle the logic in an abstract way and send signals, which the Qt Widgets version can use as well as the QML version.